# How to define an attribute to get the property name on which it is declared in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

In my DB, all the tables have the status filed, but every table has a different name for that column. For e.g. the user table has user_status and the branch table has branch_status. All these columns of different tables would be having the same value. I have created POCO entities for all and wanted to create a generic function that would perform a query on the status field of the specified POCO entity class. So I wanted to create an attribute stating that this would be the status field of the specified entity class.

So, attribute that will give me the property name on which it is declared. The attribute would be declared only on a single property in the class. Till now I have done the following and it is working but wanted to know the efficient way to achieve the same. Below is my code:

Custom Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class StatusFieldAttribute : Attribute
{


}
```

Declaration

```
    public class UserTable
    {

        public int UserId{ get; set; }

         [StatusField]
        public int UserStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class BranchTable
    {

        public int BranchId{ get; set; }

         [StatusField]
        public int BranchStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get the property name from UserTable and BranchTable having the StatusField Attribute. I have achieve the same as:

```
        Type type = typeof(UserTable);
        string statusFieldName = type.GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(StatusFieldAttribute))).FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

And the above code gives the proper output as UserStatus. But is there an efficient way to achieve the same using something like below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class StatusFieldAttribute : Attribute
{
    public StatusFieldAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        StatusFieldName = propertyName;
    }

    public string StatusFieldName { get; }


}
```

And access the StatusFieldName to get the name of the property on which the StatusField attribute is declared in a particular class.

Comment: What use will this have? What are you trying to achieve by having such an attribute?

Comment: @Herohtar In my DB, all the tables have the status filed, but every table has different name for that column. For e.g. the user table has user_status and the branch table has branch_status. All these would be having the same value.. I have created POCO entities for all and wanted to create a generic function that would perform a query on status field of the specified POCO entity class. So I have created an attribute stating that this would be the status field of the specified entity class.

Comment: Please explain what is &#39;efficiency&#39; in your understanding and why this is a concern? If you mean performance, then you need to make reflection only once per type... I&#39;m not sure why reflection does not fit your needs.

Comment: What are you going to do with property name once you get it from attribute?

Comment: @fenixil After getting the property name, I will use it in my query for e.g. select * from tableName where UserStatus = 0. And this query will be common for all tables just the UserStatus field name will change.

Comment: @fenixil  I am not sure whether the way I am using is efficient or not to retrieve the property name. If it is efficient, then I will continue with the same.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define a marker interface (prior to C# 8), and define an extension method to retrieve the proper status field, like so:

```
interface IStatusFieldMarker
{
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetStatusFieldName(this IStatusFieldMarker t) =>
        t.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Single(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(StatusFieldAttributeAttribute)))
        .Name;
    // optional getter/setter
    public static int GetStatus(this IStatusFieldMarker t) =>
        (int)(t.GetType()
        .GetProperty(GetStatusFieldName(t))
        .GetValue(t));
    public static void SetStatus(this IStatusFieldMarker t, int value)
    {
        t.GetType()
        .GetProperty(GetStatusFieldName(t))
        .SetValue(t, value);
    }
}
```

Then mark the POCO objects with the interface:

```
class Branch : IStatusFieldMarker
{
    [StatusFieldAttribute]
    public int BranchStatus { get; set; }
}
class User : IStatusFieldMarker
{
    [StatusFieldAttribute]
    public int UserStatus { get; set; }
}
```

You can then call the `GetStatusFieldName` extension method to get the field name:

```
Branch b = new Branch() { BranchStatus = 3 };
User u = new User() { UserStatus = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(b.GetStatusFieldName()); // prints BranchStatus
Console.WriteLine(u.GetStatusFieldName()); // prints UserStatus
Console.WriteLine(b.GetStatus()); // prints 3
Console.WriteLine(u.GetStatus()); // prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply created below function to get the status name

```
    public static string GetStatusField<T>(this T type) where T : Type
    {
         PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(StatusFieldAttribute)));

        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            Log.Error($"StatusFieldAttribute not found in {type.Name} ");
            throw new Exception($"StatusFieldAttribute not found in { type.Name } ");

        }
        else
            return propertyInfo.Name;

    }
```

And invoked the function as

```
Type type = typeof(UserTable);
string statusFieldName = type.GetStatusField();
```